# How to update distribution list extended field value automatically?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We have a requirement to update distribution list extended field value, Do we have any option by which we can update this value automatically, basically we need to increase subscription date (extended field) everyday by 1.
We found one way to do this by DB stored procedure where we are  updating table CONTACTFILTER_DETAIL.
Please  suggest proper solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Based on some discussions I had with R&D about dynamic date-based Contact selection in an OE distribution list a couple of years ago there is just one supported solution to this. You need to create an executable app that uses the .Net API to make the update and schedule this to run on the target server at the desired interval.

[EDIT]

Just in case you're the same person who posted this same question on the Tridion Forum, and so others can understand the approach - you can get to the ExtendedDetails fields through the ContactFilter property of the DistributionList object.